# How to make Invoke-RestMethod GET and PUT requests to Azure table storage using SAS key

Tags: azure, powershell, rest, api

This is a two-part question. I am in the process of automating tasks that a) require information from my Azure table and b) need to update specific entities in my Azure table.  I've currently been able to accomplish this by using either of the 2 provided access keys but think this is an unsafe practice and want to define individual policies for different groups and so want to transition into using generated SAS keys.

a) I can currently use SAS policies to retrieve the whole table and find the information I need but I think a better method is to perform an individual query that only pulls the single entity that matches a specific property I'm looking for (e.g. pull all properties of an entity that matches a customer ID: "000000001").  How can I change my code to accomplish this?

```
$tableName = "accountTD"
$sasReadToken = '<SAS token here>'
$tableUri = "https://$storageAccount.table.core.windows.net/$tableName$sasReadToken"

$GMTTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().toString('R')
$header = @{
    'x-ms-date' = $GMTTime;
    Accept = 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
}

$finalResult = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $tableUri -Headers $header -UseBasicParsing
$finalResult = $finalResult.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$finalResult.value
```

b) I also need to update the same entity in the table and can't seem to figure out how to authorize it with my generated SAS key.  I'm not sure whether to use Invoke-WebRequest or Invoke-RestMethod or how to go about either of them. Here's what I have so far based on my research.

```
function addUpdateEntity ($tableName, $PartitionKey, $RowKey, $entity){

    $sasReadToken = '<SAS token here>'
    $resource = "$tableName(PartitionKey='$PartitionKey',RowKey='$Rowkey')"
    $tableUri = "https://$storageAccount.table.core.windows.net/$tableName$sasReadToken"

    $GMTTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().toString('R')
    $header = @{
        'x-ms-date' = $GMTTime;
        Accept = 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
    }

    $body = $entity | ConvertTo-Json
    $item = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $tableUri -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType application/json
}

$mBody = @{
    PartitionKey = "MPS02000"
    RowKey = "2019-000101"
    appUpdateMode = "1"
    m_CustID = "000000001"
}

addUpdateEntity -TableName "atdMachines" -PartitionKey $mBody.PartitionKey -RowKey $mBody.RowKey -entity $mBody
```

Comment: is there a reason why you do not use the SDK? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell

Comment: That is what I'm currently trying to avoid using unless there is no other option due to the purposes of my task.  Believe me, I'd use SDK if I could.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my answer? It is helps, you may mark it as answer which will help others further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Pull all properties of an entity that matches a customer ID

Answer: You can use `$filter` query expression. For example, I have 2 entities in my `testTable`:

[image]

I can get the entity whose `Id` equals to `00001` by making a request as following:

GET `https://storagetest789.table.core.windows.net/testTable?{sastoken}&$filter=(Id eq '00001')`

```
$storageAccount = "storagetest789"
$tableName = "testTable"
$sasReadToken = "?sv=2019-02-02&ss=t&sr***************D"
$filter = "`$filter=(Id eq '00001')"
$tableUri = "https://$storageAccount.table.core.windows.net/$tableName$sasReadToken&$filter"

$GMTTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().toString('R')
$header = @{
    'x-ms-date' = $GMTTime;
    Accept = 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
}

$finalResult = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $tableUri -Headers $header -UseBasicParsing
$finalResult = $finalResult.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$finalResult.value
```

Result:

[image]

Q2. Update the same entity in the table

Answer:  Both `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod` are suitable for making a HTTP request here. I find some mistakes in your scripts, here is the fixed one:

```
function addUpdateEntity ($tableName, $PartitionKey, $RowKey, $entity){
    $storageAccount = "storagetest789"
    $tableName = "testTable"

    # Need write access 
    $sasWriteToken = "?sv=2019-02-02&ss=t&s*****************************D"

    $resource = "$tableName(PartitionKey='$PartitionKey',RowKey='$Rowkey')"

    # should use $resource, not $tableNmae
    $tableUri = "https://$storageAccount.table.core.windows.net/$resource$sasWriteToken"

    # should be headers, because you use headers in Invoke-RestMethod
    $headers = @{
        Accept = 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
    }

    $body = $entity | ConvertTo-Json
    $item = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $tableUri -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType application/json
}

$mBody = @{
    PartitionKey = "p1"
    RowKey = "r1"
    Id = "00001"
    Value = "new value"
}

addUpdateEntity -TableName "atdMachines" -PartitionKey $mBody.PartitionKey -RowKey $mBody.RowKey -entity $mBody
```

Result:

[image]